# GUI crashes after installing AMD Catalyst 14.9 on Ubunut 14.10

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, fglrx, catalyst

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 using kernel 3.16.0-24-generic and X.Org X Server Version 1.16.0.
I tried to install the AMD Catalyst 14.9 driver for my ATI Radeon HD 5570. After it installed without any problems using dkms I rebooted the system and ended in a black screen. No LightDM Login screen or similiar. Switching to TTY works.

Maybe somebody knows how to solve it. I looked around on launchpad and google, but couldn't find anything appropriate.

dmesg Output after Boot

[dmesglogfile.txt](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=GsYziwSe)

Interesting is line 972 and line 973

Thanks for helping

Comment: As you are using the close source driver I suggest you file a bug report with ATI.

Comment: Does this driver now work for you? I want to install it too but I don't know whether it will work.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for hours the internet finally figured out the problem. AMD Catalyst 14.9 is not supported by X.Org Server 1.16. 
However it's possible to install the latest fglrx drivers through terminal or additional driver settings.

By Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-core
```

By Additional Drivers:

> System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers